# Dynamically create struct of some type and unmarshal JSON into that instance

Tags: json, pointers, go, struct, reflection

I am creating a struct instance at runtime. The instance has been created successfully, but I can't unmarshal JSON into it.

```
type Test struct {
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
}

func create(a interface{}) {
    aType := reflect.TypeOf(a).Elem()
    elType := aType.Elem()

    f := reflect.Indirect(reflect.New(elType))

    b := []byte(`{"name": "go"}`)

    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &f)
    fmt.Println(err, f)
}

func main() {
    l := []Test{}
    create(&l)
}
```

Comment: What is the `err`?

Comment: @leafbebop no error, the value still be its zero value. json data didn't fill in.

Comment: What is the reason for passing a slice of the type when the JSON is a single object?  Did you intend to use the JSON `[{"name": "go"}]` or the value `l := Test{}`?  Both of these changes align the code and JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`reflect.Indirect()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Indirect) returns you a value of type [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value), and you should pass a pointer to `Test` (which is of type `*Test`) to [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal).

Simply use the [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) method to obtain the pointer to your `Test` struct returned by [`reflect.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New), like this:

```
f := reflect.New(elType).Interface()
b := []byte(`{"name": "go"}`)
err := json.Unmarshal(b, f)
```

With this it works, and output will be:

```
<nil> &{go}
```

Note that `f` will be of `interface{}` type, holding the `*Test` pointer value. If you need the struct value, you may use type assertion, like this:

```
t := *f.(*Test)
fmt.Println(t)
```

This prints:

```
{go}
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/k6CK8t6bWw6).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to use reflect, instead you can do the following:

```
type Test struct {
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
}

func create(a interface{}) {
    b := []byte(`[{"name": "go"}]`)

    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &a)
    fmt.Println(err, a)
}

func main() {
    l := []Test{}
    create(&l)
}
```

Comment: l should be slice

Comment: edited, it errors with slice and that hardcoded json

Comment: you changed the `b` defination... so this is not what I need

Comment: what you want is encoding an object into an array, code works fine in that case too but returns not nil error

Answer (score 1):

The code  `reflect.Indirect(reflect.New(elType))`
returns a `reflect.Value` instead of a concrete value of `elType`. And when you unmarshal it, the json package looks into the `reflect.Value` struct which has no field `Name`, so it does nothing.

Instead, you should use `reflect.Value.Interface()` to turn it into an `interface{}` holding the concrete type.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/sW9mJd8fKMb